# Integral of function in R

Tags: r

I would like to get the integral of function `f1`, how can I solve the following problem in R?

```
      f = function(x)dbeta(x, .5, .5)
      >  integrate(function(x) f(x), lower = 0, upper = 1)
      1 with absolute error < 3e-06

      f1 = function(x)dbeta(x, .5, .5)^2
      >  integrate(function(x) f1(x), lower = 0, upper = 1)
      Error in integrate(function(x) f1(x), lower = 0, upper = 1) : 
      maximum number of subdivisions reached
```

Comment: The function you're integrating is `1/x*1/(1-x)*constants`.  You can integrate `1/sqrt(x)*1/sqrt(1-x)*constants`, which is why `f` is integrable, but `f1` is not integrable since the inverse function `1/x` diverges.

Comment: @user1362215 if the OP changed the limits to $ 0 + \epsilon , 1- \epsilon $, there'd be an answer, right?  So maybe we need to ask why xe is asking this question.

Comment: If you changed the limits, then that would defeat the purpose, and the integral would still be pretty large unless \epsilon was large.  Maybe "undefined" is really the answer rose is looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first integral converges to 1, even though the integrand approaches ∞ at the limits. The second integral doesn't converge. Conveniently, we can show this both analytically and numerically.

> `I` = ∫ x<sup>-1</sup> (1-x)<sup>-1</sup> dx = log(x) - log(1-x)

Substituting (ε, 1- ε) for (0,1) gives:

> `I` = 2 log(1/ε)

So `I` → ∞ as ε → 0

We can see this numerically in R:

```
eps <- c(10^-(5:13))
g    <- function(eps) integrate(function(x) dbeta(x,.5,.5), 
                                lower = 0+eps, upper = 1-eps)$value
g.sq <- function(eps) integrate(function(x) dbeta(x,.5,.5)^2, 
                                lower = 0+eps, upper = 1-eps)$value
(g.lim   <- sapply(eps, g))
(g.sq.lim<- sapply(eps, g.sq))

plot(eps, g.sq.lim, col="red", type="b", ylim=c(0,7),ylab="", log="x")
par(new=T)
plot(eps, g.lim, col="blue", type="b", ylim=c(0,7),ylab="", log="x")
```

[image]